# PHP header_redirect with multiple variables

Tags: php, redirect, header

I am writing a PHP script that will redirect based on a link like this:

```
header_redirect($_GET['redirect']);
```

And the URL being:

```
https://www.url.com/index.php?change_language=english&redirect=other_page.php?category=1234&limit=24
```

As you can see, the actual page is

```
https://www.url.com/index.php?change_language=english
```

and the redirect is then to another page with multiple variables like:

```
&redirect=other_page.php?category=1234&limit=24
```

However, when I run the link above, I only get redirected to "other_page.php" and the additional variables are lost.

How would I achieve this?

Comment: All URL params are consumed by `index.php` unless you escape the `&redirect=` value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this problem using some encryption and decryption trick, I have used `base64_encode` and `base64_decode()` function to solve your problem.

**Step1: in your html page**

```
<?php $redirectUrl = base64_encode('other_page.php?category=1234&limit=24'); ?>
<a href="index.php?change_language=english&redirect=<?php echo $redirectUrl;?>">Link1 </a>
```

**Step 2:** in your `header_redirect()` function, you can use  `base64_decode()` function decode the redirect stings and get the expected one.

```
function header_redirect($redirect){
      $redirect = base64_decode($redirect); // you can get the expected redirected url with query string
     //your redirect script
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you're trying to do.

**Option 1**: Use [http_build_query](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php).

Try:

```
$target=$_GET['redirect'];
unset($_GET['redirect']);
$query_str=http_build_query($_GET);
header_redirect($target.'?'.$query_str);
```

If your starting URL is this:

```
https://www.url.com/index.php?change_language=english&redirect=other_page.php&category=1234&limit=24
```

You would then be redirected to:

```
https://www.url.com/other_page.php?change_language=english&category=1234&limit=24
```

**Option 2**: Use [rawurlencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rawurlencode.php) and [rawurldecode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rawurldecode.php).

However, if your goal is to be redirected to whatever you have stored in `$_GET['redirect']` (and ignore any other variables in the URL), then you would need to encode the `other_page.php&category=1234&limit=24` bit before you put it into your starting URL. This will effectively escape the special characters and allow you to simply call `header_redirect(rawurldecode($_GET['redirect']));`.

Say your starting URL is then:

```
https://www.url.com/index.php?change_language=english&redirect=other_page.php%3Fcategory%3D1234%26limit%3D24
```

You would then be redirected to:

```
https://www.url.com/other_page.php?category=1234&limit=24
```